# Tabbed bar application buttons blocked when NSUrlSendAssynchronousrequest operation running

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, uitabbar

I have a tabbed bar application in which one of the buttons loads the content of a webpage to a UIWebView.
The problem I am facing is that while the connection attempting to fetch the data the tab bar buttons are non responsive until either the page is done loading or connection has failed.
Is there a better way to perform this operation so the user can switch out of that tab if he/she changes their mind for example.
Thanks and here is the code:

```
- (void)loadThrillsSite
{
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://www.Thrills.in";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [self.webView loadRequest:request];
         else if (error != nil) {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error!" message:@"Failed to connect to server\nPlease check your internet connection and try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
         }
     }];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{
    [hudImageView removeFromSuperview];

    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

    [patternView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView`'s loadRequest method description:

> Connects to a given URL by initiating an asynchronous client request.

It already makes a asynchronous call so you do not need to use another block. Just call `[self.webView loadRequest:request];` You can handle errors on `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` method.

Other notes: Your url is not working right now and do not do any UI related work like showing an alert view on background thread. Hope it helps.

```
- (void)loadThrillsSite
{
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://www.Thrills.in";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{
    [hudImageView removeFromSuperview];

    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

    [patternView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error!" message:@"Failed to connect to server\nPlease check your internet connection and try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Boran, I do have the UIWebview delegate set up somewhere else in my code. The URL is not working because it is not the real URL name I'm using. My issue is that the UI button are frozen while it's trying to connect like when wifi is disabled. Otherwise they work fine but regardless of internet connectivity the app needs to always be responsive

Comment: You should check internet connectivity with reachability before this stuff. After that only delegate methods are working on UI thread so your UI must be responsive at that moment. Something else can be blocking your UI like an animation, debug your threads and see what's happening on Thread 1.

Comment: I changed my code to look like yours. It has the delegate methods instead of completions blocks. for some unknown reason it works better that way, I would think that they both ways would yield same result, but now it works. Thank you